# TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method 'mapDefaultAction' with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I was getting error with express-resource so I have applied patch as mentioned in following link.
As mentioned in following question at stack overflow:
[express-namespace and express-resource wont allow map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747825/express-namespace-and-express-resource-wont-allow-map)

I employed following command: 
npm install git://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource.git#add/express3x-support

but now I am getting following error:

```
    C:\Data\work\node\example\www\example\node_modules\express-resource\index.js:63
    if (actions[key]) this.mapDefaultAction(key, actions[key]);
    TypeError: Object function app(req, res){ app.handle(req, res); } has no method
    'mapDefaultAction'
    at Function.Resource (C:\Data\work\node\example\www\example\node_modules\
    express-resource\index.js:63:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Data\work\node\example\www\mixerade\app.js:23:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

can anyone please suggest what could be the possible reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide some context? ie: code sample.

Comment: I am using express-3.0.0rc4 and express-resource-0.2.4. when I have installed both the packages and try to use express-resource. I was getting error mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747825/express-namespace-and-express-resource-wont-allow-map                                                                      after that I apply fix as per mentioned in  that  question but now I am getting error mentioned above.